# Assigning values in StringBuilder array using {}

Tags: java, arrays, stringbuilder

I can't do this:

`StringBuilder[] textArray = new StringBuilder("Word1", "Word2", "Word3", "e.t.c");`

Do I do it wrong? Or is it just not possible? Are there better ways?

Comment: You're creating __one__ `StringBuilder`, not an array of `StringBuilder`s.

Comment: What do you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is a link to StringBuilder javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

As you can see there is no constructor with a vararg parameter which can accept any number of strings. You can pass only one string to the constructor. But the following example may be what you want:

```
new StringBuilder("one string").append("second string").append("third")
```

but this example will create one string builder. If you want to create one StringBuilder for every string, you can use streams.

```
        Arrays.stream(new String[]{"one", "second", "third"})
            .map(st -> new StringBuilder(st))
            .toArray();
```

But this can be to match for smbd who has just started to learn Java.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it.

```
StringBuilder[] textArray = Stream
        .of("Word1", "Word2", "Word3")
        .map(StringBuilder::new)
        .toArray(StringBuilder[]::new);
```

If you already have an array of strings, you could do it like this.

```
String[] array = {"Word1", "Word2", "Word3"};

StringBuilder[] textArray = Arrays.stream(array)
        .map(StringBuilder::new)
        .toArray(StringBuilder[]::new);
```

Either way, they print the same.

```
for (StringBuilder sb : textArray) {
    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

prints

```
Word1
Word2
Word3
```

The main points are:

- map the string to a `StringBuilder` object
- specify the array type in the `toArray` method